# Is there a way to log out of an sql database?

Tags: php, sql

Ok so I'm trying to create a simple login page.

I can do it successfully but it seems I can't get multiple computers to access the page.  I've created multiple different users on my mysql database that individually credential their way into it and query it for data, BUT AGAIN only one computer it seems will be let in.

I've set the PHP session variable as well to contain login info.

My simple questions is:

**Is there a way to log out of the db and destroy my session to perhaps let other computers access the username after one has finished**

Could it be the session or the db login that is still lingering one computer that is causing this?

I know my code is a mess:

```
 <?php session_start(); 
    include("password.php"); ?>
    ...
    <body>

 <div class="main_content">
 <?php 
   $submenarray = array(
    'Purpose' => 'purpose.php',
     'Leading Self'  => 'leadingself.php',
    'Leading with Strategy' => 'leadingwithstrategy.php',
    'Leading People' => 'leadingpeople.php',
    'Leading for Results' => 'leadingforresults.php',
   );

   insert_header_with_params(0,0,$submenarray);
 ?>

 <div class="content_body">
   <div class="description">
    <h1 style="margin-left:5%;">
     User <span style="color:red"> Login</span>
    </h1>
    <p></p>
   </div>




<?
  global $USERS;
  global $_SESSION;
  $USERS= getUsers("member1","password");
  $record;
  $max_login_attempts = 3;



  if(isset($_POST['password'])){$_SESSION["password"] = $_POST["password"];}

  if($_GET["logged"] == "false"){
    $_SESSION["logged"] = "";
  }

  if(isset($_POST['Field1'])){
    $record = getRecord($_POST["Field1"],removeUnwantedChar($_POST["Field1"]),$_POST["password"]);}


if ($_POST["ac"]=="log") { /// do after login form is submitted  
    if ($record[19]==$_POST["password"]) {   
       $_SESSION["logged"]=$_POST["Field1"]; 
      $sql = "UPDATE `leading_initiatives` SET `Login Attempts`='0'
          WHERE `Name`='".$_POST['Field1']."'";
          sql_command($sql,removeUnwantedChar($_POST["Field1"]),$_POST["password"]);

     } else {  
       if($record[20] < $max_login_attempts){
       setRecord('Login Attempts',$record[20]+1,$record[1],removeUnwantedChar($_POST["Field1"]),$_POST["password"]);
         echo '<p style="padding-left:20%;">Incorrect username/password. '.($max_login_attempts-$record[20]).' attempts remaining.</p>'; 
       }else{
       echo 'max reached';
     } 
     }
} 

  $attempts = $record[20];
  if($attempts > $max_login_attempts)
    $_SESSION["locked_out"] = "true";

if (array_key_exists($_SESSION["logged"],$USERS)) { //// check if user is logged or not  
  echo "<p style='padding-left:20%;'>Logged in: ".$_SESSION["logged"]."</p>"; //// if user is logged show a message 
  echo "<a href='http://newsite.com' style='padding-left:20%;'>form</a></br></br>";    
}elseif($_SESSION["locked_out"] == "true"){
  echo "<script>
  window.location.replace('site/max_attempts.php');
  </script>";
}
    else { //// if not logged show login form 
      echo '<form id="the_form" name="the_form" action="http://site/login.php" method="post" style="padding-left:20%;">
    <input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log">'; 
  echo 'Username: <select id="Field1" name="Field1">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
       <option value="Anton, Manny">Anton, Manny</option>
     </select>';
     echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />'; 
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Login" />'; 
     echo '</form>';
}


  if($_GET["logged"] == "false"){
    echo "<script>document.forms['the_form']['Field1'].value = ".$_GET["Field1"].";</script>";
  } 
  ?>



    </div> <!--end content body-->



  </div>  <!--end the main content div-->

</body>
​
```

Comment: Can you share some code with us? Something sounds odd here.

Comment: Multiple users can share the same credentials when connecting to database. To put it in simpler terms, this is not a problem on the DB. It looks like a larger issue. You said that only one user can access your "db". It might be that you're stuck with HTTP pipelining "feature" of your web server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to destroy a session. This one is very thorough:

```
// destroy session the correct way
function destroySession() {
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get('session.use_cookies')) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params['httponly']
        );
    }
    session_destroy();
}
```

Be sure to call `session_start();` before `destroySession();` ... and the session + session cookie goes away.

Comment: You must be right.  Why is set cookie setting the cookies to these values, wouldn't I want to make them null or empty?  Would you mind explaining what some of these functions are doing?  Also, couldn't I just simply call session_destroy?

Comment: session_destroy() works fine, but the session ID remains in the cookie, as with anything else if you use cookies for anything else. what this does is cycle through every cookie, and set it to expired, which is as close to deleting cookies that we can get.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding sessions to the php pages like:

```
session_start();
```

It must be added at the top of the php page and once the work is done, destroy the session:

```
session_destroy();
```

Also, try closing database connections:

```
$conn = NULL;
```

The above code for closing database connection is for PHP PDOs. If you are using mysqli, use:

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

By the way, I've never faced or heard such an issue. Perhaps ports or some incorrect parameter is causing the issue?